Why is a wrong checksum TCP packet acknowledged by kernel?
I'm delevloping a backend system. I send a HTTP request to backend server, the request packets are broken into fragments since the smaller MTU settting in the intermediate gateway. And the server receives all the fragments and defragment them. Some packets' TCP checksum is incorrect since some fragments's payload is corrupted. But those packets are acknowledged instead of discarded by server.

So, the server receives the corrputed TCP payload and can't process them properly instead of just discard the packet to make client retransmit the correct packet.
Kernel version: 2.6.32-696
The TCP packet with wrong checksum should be discarded by kernel and the client will retransmit it.
Edit:
I captured the traffic in the server. Most of the defragmentations have a correct checksum except two.


I'm pretty sure that the packets are not corrupt but you just misinterpret what is shown in Wireshark: with TCP checksum offloading the checksum on the captured packet is often not what is actually transmitted on the wire. That's why Wireshark offers an option to not check the validity of the checksum.

Hi, Steffen. @SteffenUllrich Thanks for your reply.
Those two packets marked as "TCP CHECKSUM INCORRECT" by wireshark is in the receive side. In my opinion, when TX checksum offload is on, the TCP checksum is a partial checksum contribution from the pseudo header. When RX checksum offload is on, TCP checksum validation is performed by NIC instead of CPU, but the checksum value captured by tcpdump should be correct. Correct me if I'm wrong please.  Thanks!

It is impossible to derive from your question where you did the packet capture (client or server) and thus if these packets are received or send. Since at least in your image all packets in one direction have a wrong checksum I think it is fair to assume that this looks like a systematic problem from capturing the packets, not a problem in the packets themselves.

Hi, @SteffenUllrich. Sorry for the unclear and insufficient description. Not all the received packets but only those two have a wrong checksum. And the payload of those two packets was indeed corrupted.

It seems to me that it is the ACK packets whose checksum is incorrect, not the packets they are acknowledging, and that the packets they are acknowledging are of zero length. Is there a genuine problem here?

@patrick: "And the payload of those two packets was indeed corrupted." - only when viewed in Wireshark or also in the application, i.e. is this a problem of capturing only or is it actual data corruption? If this is only for capturing than it would explain why you see the ACK, since from the perspective of the kernel all is fine. Also, is this a single event or can you reliably reproduce this?

hi, @SteffenUllrich I can reliably reproduce it. The corrupted packets are only viewed in wireshark. I'm not quite sure whether the payload is corrupted from the server's perspective since I can't print the payload received by the server now. But I can infer that the request payload is corrupted from the server's response.
The request payload is a JSON string, the server's response indicates that the request payload can't be converted into a JSON object. By contrast, server can converts the request payload into a JSON object and process it in the case of normal. Thank.

hi, @user207421. Seq 36904 and 38352 are the packets whose length is 1448 with wrong checksum.

@patrick: Since you can reproduce it - are these always packets with the same content which are corrupt? Or packets at a specific position in the data stream? Or something else common between the tests?

Hi, @SteffenUllrich The corrupted packets are caused by the intermediate gateway's bug. Suppose two big TCP packets(seq1, seq2) were sent to the server through the gateway, they were broken into four fragments(seq1-frag1, seq1-frag2, seq2-frag1, seq2-frag2) with the same identification in the IP header (intermediate gateway's bug) . Those fragments arrived at the server in the order of seq1-frag1, seq2-frag2, seq2-frag1, seq1-frag2, and seq1-frag1 and seq2-frag2 were defragmented into a packet with corrupted payload and a wrong TCP checksum. The same is true for seq2-frag1 and seq1-frag2.
